# Explaining the Explain in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-execution-plan, explain

```
Explain 
sel * from sandbox.comapny_employees ce
    left join 
    sandbox.comapny_age ca
    on ce.age=ca.age and ce.age>42
```

some times its really confusing to understand how explain plan was created.
below explain plan totally skipped the condition "ce.age>42" from steps, we know all the records get printed and this condition will not work but how this explain was created to discard the condition.
Please let me know if table structure is required.

```
1) First, we lock sandbox.ca for read on a reserved RowHash to
 prevent global deadlock.  
2) Next, we lock sandbox.ce for read on a reserved RowHash to prevent
 global deadlock.  
3) We lock sandbox.ca for read, and we lock sandbox.ce for read.  
4) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from sandbox.ce by way of an
 all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 2 (all_amps),
 which is redistributed by the hash code of (sandbox.ce.age) to all
 AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 2 by row hash.  The size
 of Spool 2 is estimated with high confidence to be 3 rows (81
 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.01 seconds.  
5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from sandbox.ca by way of a RowHash
 match scan with a condition of ("sandbox.ca.age >= 43"), which is
 joined to Spool 2 (Last Use) by way of a RowHash match scan.
 sandbox.ca and Spool 2 are right outer joined using a merge join,
 with condition(s) used for non-matching on right table ("age >= 43"),
 with a join condition of ("age = sandbox.ca.age").  The result
 goes into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.
 The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 4 rows
 (176 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.02 seconds.
6) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
 in processing the request.
 -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
 statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.03 seconds.
```

Comment: the moment I convert left join to inner join condition will appear in the plan.

Comment: Well, I can spot `"sandbox.ca.age >= 43"` which is the same as `ca_age > 42`. Of course it's returning all rows because there's no `WHERE`-condition, it's just an additional condition evaluated during the join and check for rows over age, but those rows are still joined and return NULLs.

Comment: That i agree sir , same condition will appear if i put where insted of and along with ce.age>42 as a residual condition , i wanted to know how td know when a condition is residual, is it just by looking at where clause ?

Comment: A *residual condition* is a search-condition applied during that step (usually due to a WHERE-clause). For the Outer Join this was a join-condition only, thus `no residual conditions`.

Comment: looks like the optimizer is programmed to ignore all the 'and' condition in case of left join or right join while creating explain plan.

Comment: It doesn't ignore those conditions, but in case of an Outer Join they're no search-conditions. http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_109A/ch02.4.075.html